# Implementing copy-paste directive in my table using Angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying some data in tabular format. I am trying to add the ability to copy contents of one cell and paste into another. i know I have to do something like

element.on('ctrl-c',function(e){
  $scope.textToBeCopied = element.innerHTML;
})

and then let the cursor move to the relevant position and implement a similar paste function.

Those with knowhow of how to implement this feature kindly advice.

I have a plnkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YyZLVKtRAR1OYGey0FYj

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. 
Those who wanna take a look or offer a better solution please see the plnkr.co here

http://plnkr.co/edit/YyZLVKtRAR1OYGey0FYj

Focus on the file copyOn.js

This is where I have defined the copy-paste directive